# How do I get great auto indenting with Vim and Yaml?

Tags: vim, yaml

Right now I am using 
`set autoindent`
when I edit Yaml files in Vim, and it works okay by just copying the previous line's indent when you start a new line. I can't help but feel like it could be a little smarter, though. What would be great is if starting a new line after
`foo: "bar"`
could keep the same indent level, but starting a line after
`foo:`
would add an additional level of indent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xavier inspired me to hack at this a bit, and I came up with [my own little indent script for Yaml](https://gist.github.com/871107). It doesn't handle any of the more advanced Yaml features, but it does what I originally asked for.

To use this, you can just drop it into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/yaml.vim` (assuming you are using `set ftplugin on`).

Answer (score 4):

Specific indentation rules are stored on a language basis in :
`$VIMRUNTIME\indent\foo.vim` for language `foo`.

On my default installation, I have got `ruby.vim`, `haml.vim` and many other but no `yaml.vim`.

You could create an `indent\yaml.vim` to get the indentation rules you want. I have quickly tried to search online if something similar was available but I have not find anything.